# página "not-found.tsx" en Next.js no funciona

Tags: javascript, next.js

Actualmente vengo siguiente el curso de Next.js en Youtube del canal "Dave Gray"(lista de reproducción: Next.js Tutorial for Beginners), en el cuarto video que trata sobre "SSG, SSR & ISR" muestra como utilizar la función notFound de Next.js (import {notFound} from "next/navigation") para mostrar un mensaje personalizado sobre aquellas rutas que no existen en una aplicación.

Resulta que, en cierta parte de la implementación de dicha función, obtengo un error como el que se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, ese es el problema en cuestión que quiero solucionar, tener en cuenta que en el video tutorial este error no se presenta, algo estoy haciendo mal?

Lista de reproducción: [Next.js for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1HzFvXgrCs&list=PL0Zuz27SZ-6Pk-QJIdGd1tGZEzy9RTgtj&index=4)

Repositorio del curso: [Github repo](https://github.com/gitdagray/next-js-course)

Cabe resaltar que, estoy utilizando exactamente los mismos archivos con su contenido en un nuevo proyecto de Next.js, ya que en el repositorio no viene incluida la carpeta "node_modules". Entonces, es exactamente el mismo contenido que el del video, pero pues obtengo el error mencionado.

Para tener el contexto completo sobre el problema, recomiendo clonar el repositorio e ir hacia la carpeta "next04" , y también ver el video en cuestión.

Finalmente, agradezco que puedan tomarse el tiempo de responder, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.